# What online collaboration sites do you know?

Tags: project-management, collaboration

Basically I need a hosted solution, where one can create an account for a project and the distributed team members can interact through that site during the project implementation. I know a lot of such software but not a hosted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com) is the most popular one.

Comment: Which is a shame, it has an almost unusable UI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying the [CodeSpaces](http://www.codespaces.com/) now. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I use **codeplex.com** from Microsoft and find it excellent, it now accepts svn connections as well as Team System.

An excellent alternative would be **code.google.com**, which I've not found wanting.

I would propose that both of these are very popular and of the highest quality and many will have opinions on which better suits your needs.  I  can't give a narrower answer without knowing more of your particular needs and preferences.

Comment: Looks like these sites host open source projects only.

Comment: correct, given that, codespaces does look interesting and try it myself.  i wasn't sure what kind of project you were working on.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [VersionOne](http://www.versionone.com/) offers both hosted and onsite web based versions of their tools.  The Team Edition is also free for a limited time.  [Rally Software](http://www.rallydev.com/) offers basically the same deal (hosted and onsite) versions of its software.  Again, the community edition is free.